# How to pass an async object to a props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm practicing react and how to incorporate react to firebase/firestore. Now I want to make something like a CMS using firestore database. I have successfully fetch data from the database and confirmed it by console log. But the problem is whenever I tried to pass the object to be used as my props it throws me an error. But if I add the code after the page is fully loaded, the data is successfully loaded and throws me an error after I refresh the page.

I think it has something to do with asynchronous request but I don't know how to pull it off.

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore(app);

const [data, setData] = useState({});

const fetchData =async () => {

  
        const docRef = doc(db, "data", "RSVp8ljO95Dpwa0oSs0G");

        const docSnap =  await getDoc(docRef);

        const dataTest = docSnap.data();

        await setData(dataTest);
        console.log("Document data:", dataTest);
}


useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [])



return (
    
    <div style={{overflow: 'hidden'}}>
        <NavBar />           


            <div style={{width: '100%', height:'81vh', padding: '5%', overflow:'scroll'}}>
            
                <Container >

                    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">    
                       
                        <TrainingSchedule 
                            **date={data.event1.date} //I want to pass the object here but throws me an error**
                            month='SEPT' 
                            eventTitle='Lets Get to know each other' 
                            eventDescription='Have a drink with our finest coach and enjoy the summer' 
                            time='1pm'
                            backgroundColor= 'CadetBlue'
                        />
```

......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Juls: Welcome to StackOverflow.

In your example, you're trying to access properties on `data` that don't exist in the first render (before the effect hook runs). That's why you're getting the error. Instead, check to make sure the object and properties that you need exist before trying to access them:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.15.7/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useEffect, useState} = React;

async function getDataFromAPI () {
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  return { event1: { date: '2021-09-18' } };
}

function Example () {
  // Leave the state value undefined instead of initializing it as an empty object
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const fetchedData = await getDataFromAPI();
      setData(fetchedData);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        // Check if the data exists before trying to access its properties:
        data
          ? (<div>{data.event1.date}</div>)
          : (<div>Data is being fetched...</div>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: Hi @jsejcksn thank you so much! Now I understand why the code throws the error. I didn't thought of this from the very beginning. Couldn't done it without your help. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it! @Juls

Answer (score 0):

please provide us with the error so that we can fully understand the problem.
but for now, try this :

`date={data.event1.date || null}` 
this should cause the date to become null if the data is not ready, then get updated in the next render which is caused by setState.